# Session pull and/or flush does not remove session data

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I have this line of code in my login method

```
Session::put('msg','Welcome user');
```

And with a simple route a get through AJAX the value of that message and then delete it ( in theory ) (It's like a flash message):

```
public function getMessage( ){

    $msg = Session::pull('msg','');// tried this 

    Session::flush();// and/or this 

    return $msg;
}
```

Still the message from session is not removed. I want it behave like a flash message . Why the value still persists if I used `Session::pull()` and\or `Session::flush()`?

Comment: Ho can you say that session still persists? Did you echo that session somewhere?

Comment: My ajax call always outputs the message very time a refresh the page. I just want it to output the message once and the delete it. I've searched in the laravel's session folder. The value is still there....

Comment: Please post your full code with ajax.

Comment: It is an AngularJs service that does the Ajax part.  It looks like this ` $http.get('app/message') ` . But I don't think there is a JS problem here...

Comment: But where did you echo your session? You only show us two lines. `$msg = Session::pull('msg','');    Session::flush();`

Comment: `return $msg;`  returns the message in my Ajax call. I see the message in the network response view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103601/discussion-between-boyd-and-mr-engineer).

Answer (score 0):

laravel have already a system of session flash,to set data in session flash

```
Session::flash('msg', 'Event Created');
```

and then when you show this session a single time,it will automatically remove,you don't need to think about it

```
Session::get('msg')
```

Comment: I tried this before. It doesn't work. That's why create my method. `Session::flash('msg', 'Event Created');` doesn't do anything. I outputted the session file content and the 'flash' value is empty 's:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}'